# SQL Count Records, Group By Date and fill in missing date?

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL Query that counts Orders and groups them by each Day (Date).

Thus the following results:

```
01/02/2014 = 10
02/02/2014 = 2
05/02/2014 = 7
07/02/2014 = 4
```

Query:

```
SELECT TOP(@NumberOfRecords) DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, AddedDate)) AS Date,       COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS Count 
          FROM OrderSpecs
          GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, AddedDate)) 
          ORDER BY Date DESC
```

My question is, how can I get my Query to fill in any of the in-between missing dates and set the Count value to 0?

Example Desired Results:

```
    01/02/2014 = 10
    02/02/2014 = 2
    03/02/2014 = 0
    04/02/2014 = 0
    05/02/2014 = 7
    06/02/2014 = 0
    07/02/2014 = 4
```

Many thanks for you time taken out to read this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @mindate DATETIME
DECLARE @maxdate DATETIME
DECLARE @diff INT
SELECT @maxdate = MAX(addeddate), @mindate = MIN(addeddate) FROM OrderSpecs
SET @diff = DATEDIFF(DAY,  @mindate,@maxdate)
;WITH cte(dt,level)
AS
(
    SELECT  @mindate AS dt, 0 AS level 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day,1,cte.dt),level + 1 from cte WHERE level < @diff
)
SELECT dt,c FROM cte
LEFT JOIN 
(
   SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0,AddedDate)) AddedDt, COUNT(ID) AS c  
   FROM OrderSpecs 
   GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0,AddedDate))
) tab
ON cte.dt = tab.AddedDt 
OPTION (MaxRecursion 32767);
```

CTE is written to generate all dates in a date range. With this a `LEFT JOIN` of aggregation resultset is done.

Disclaimer: this query would not work if the date range is more that 32767 days

Comment: Thanks for this, I really appreciate you getting back to me. One problem is that the dt column is returning a time part of the first date record and applying it to all of the other dates. i.e. **20/12/2013 14:42:56** then the next record is **21/12/2013 14:42:56**. Your solution for filling in blank dates is working, however bar the first item returned, all count results are null and the first count result item is 1. The result I'm looking for should be **Date:20/12/2013 Count:4**, **Date:21/12/2013 Count:0**, **Date:22/12/2013 Count:7**.

Comment: have made some edits in my answer based on your input. The solution was written assuming the AddedDate is Date field, but actually it is a a datetime field, I guess that is reason of unexpected result. Let me know the edit worked or not!

Comment: Thanks for the amendment Dipendu Paul. I really appreciate your assistance. Initially your amendment didn't work, however I edited the **DECLARE mindate DATETIME** & **DECLARE maxdate DATETIME** to **DATE** and now it appears to be working as expected. I need to check the returned results more thoroughly but on the face it appears to work really well. I can't thank you enough for your assistance with this.

Comment: Right, the variables should be DATE type. Glad it worked. Let me know if you find any other issue.

Comment: Yea the database fields are DATETIME, however I wanted to group and count items based on just the date element and ignoring the time element. Anyhow, you're solution works really well. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you issue a lot of such queries then you can create a calendar table that contain all calendar dates

```
CREATE TABLE calendar([date] DATE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
```

And then use an outer join

```
SELECT TOP(@NumberOfRecords) 
       c.Date, COALESCE(o.Count, 0) Count
  FROM Calendar c LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, AddedDate)) AS Date,
         COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS Count 
    FROM OrderSpecs
   GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, AddedDate)) 
) o
    ON c.Date = o.Date
 ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Output:

```
|       DATE | COUNT |
|------------|-------|
| 2014-02-07 |     4 |
| 2014-02-06 |     0 |
| 2014-02-05 |     7 |
| 2014-02-04 |     0 |
| 2014-02-03 |     0 |
| 2014-02-02 |     2 |
| 2014-02-01 |    10 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/551ff/1)** demo

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I appreciate you offering your solution. I don't particularity want to go down the route of creating a table filled with dates. But I understand where you're coming from.

Comment: @RobHurd You're quite welcome. Just make sure that you get optimal performance in production.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along the lines of this. I've not tested it thoroughly but in principle if you're unioning it'll ditch extras. You may need to do an order on the output to put it in the right order

```
SELECT SS1.Date, Count
FROM
( 
DECLARE @mindate Date
DECLARE @maxdate Date
WITH DateTable
AS
(
     SELECT CAST(@mindate as Date) AS [DATE]
     UNION ALL
     SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, [DATE]) FROM DateTable 
     WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, [DATE]) BETWEEN @mindate AND @maxdate
)
SELECT dt.[DATE], 0 [Count] FROM [DateTable] dt
UNION ALL

TOP(@NumberOfRecords) DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, AddedDate)) AS Date,           COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS Count 
      FROM OrderSpecs
      GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, AddedDate)) 
      ORDER BY Date DESC
) SS1
ORDER BY [Date]
```

Is it possible that you know the start and end date that you could pass in as seed dates?

Comment: I am getting this error `The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement complete`

Comment: How wide is your date range? My guess is more than 100 days? - Although, I like @peterm solution more